# The ensemble average in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In the canonical ensemble the probability of finding the system at a given energy is:

$$P(E)=\frac{f(E)e^{-\frac{E}{k_{b}T}}}{\sum_{E'}f(E')e^{-\frac{E'}{k_{b}T}}}$$

where f(E) is the number of microstates at the energy E. Which I understand is just a probability weighted by how many degenerate microstates the system at energy E has. However I do not understand how the following steps follow mathematically:

$$\langle E \rangle = \sum_{r}P_{r}E_{r}=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{r}E_{r}e^{-\frac{E_{r}}{k_{b}T}}$$

It is strange to me that the partition function, a summation over energy states in this case $Z=\sum_{E'}f(E')e^{-\frac{E'}{k_{b}T}}$, can be brought out of this sum, where $\sum_{r}$ is the sum over all microstates.

Comment: $Z$ doesn't depend on $r$, which is a dummy variable inside the outer sum, so it can be pulled out, just like a function of $x$ can be pulled out of an integral over $y$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!